# Multiple jwplayers using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, jwplayer, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm probably going about this the wrong way, but I'm trying to create a vertical scrolling web page that gets populated by multiple videos.  The data for each video is coming from an endpoint on my backend, and I want to use ng-repeat to generate a jwplayer for each video.

What I've got at the moment is something like:

```
<div id="repeatingvids" ng-repeat="video in retrieved_videos">
    <div id="jwplayer{{$index}}">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jwplayer("jwplayer{{$index}}").setup({
        file: {{retrieved_videos[{{$index}}].video_url}},
        type: 'mp4',
        width: '100%',
        aspectratio: '16:9',
        controls: 'true',
        }
      });
    </script>
</div>
```

Where the important part of the controller looks like

```
$http.get(getVideos).success(function(results)
    {
      $scope.retrieved_videos = results;
    });
```

Now before someone says something I absolutely know that code in the script tag is garbage, and that those data bind tags are totally invalid, I just put them there to give some sort of idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I originally tried setting up all the jwplayers inside of the http success callback, looping through the results, but because of the asynchronous nature of $http.get, there was nothing for ng-repeat to loop through on load, and loading the page after callback resulted in jwplayer('element').settings being undefined because the elements of course weren't there.

So I'm in a jam, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have an example link to where this is being run?

Comment: See angular-jwplayer, which may get you further along: https://github.com/ds62987/angular-jwplayer  That said, I'm having trouble with it myself...

Answer (score 0):

You must include angular and jwplayer on one page.
If you have a key for jwplayer just include it as you normally would according to their docs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jwplayer.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="YOUR_JW_PLAYER_KEY";</script>
```

Add any jwplayer setup options you want to an object in your angular controller.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.options = {
        file: "pathToMyVideo/myvideo.mp4",
        image: "pathToMyImage/image.jpg", // optionnal
        height: 360,
        width: 640
    };

}]);
```

Add the element to the page and set the "setup" attribute to the variable you set up in your controller. It is also a good idea to give the element an id by setting player-id variable.

```
<div ng-controller='HomeCtrl'>  
    <jwplayer setup="options"></jwplayer>
</div>
```

[Click here to get full code](https://github.com/ds62987/angular-jwplayer)